# Mobile Image Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, carousel

[iphone image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3edsR.png)Hi All I am trying to add 2 image sliders on the same page.I need to make it something similiar to https://www.flipp.com/ iphone image but it should be automatic and the images should change automatically

```html
<div class="feat-image">
  <img src="device-iphone-6.png" alt="Screenshot of Flipping" />
  <img src="btn-appstore.png" alt="Screenshot of Flipping" />
  <div class="feat-screens">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Carousel items -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="active item">
          <img src="IMG_5476.png" alt="Screenshot of Flipping" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="screen-flipp.png" alt="Screenshot of Shopping List" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="IMG_5488.png" alt="Screenshot of Clip" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="IMG_5475.png" alt="Screenshot of Search" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="IMG_5485.png" alt="Screenshot of Item Details" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="flyer.png" alt="Screenshot Notifications" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="IMG_5484.png" alt="Screenshot of Sync" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="/images/flipp/coupons/features/screen-coupons.png" alt="Screenshot of Discount Slider" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Carousel nav -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="feat-image">
  <img src="nexus5.png" alt="Screenshot of Flipping" />
  <img src="btn-appstore.png" alt="Screenshot of Flipping" />
  <div class="feat-screens">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Carousel items -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="active item">
          <img src="IMG_5476.png" alt="Screenshot of Flipping" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="screen-flipp.png" alt="Screenshot of Shopping List" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="IMG_5488.png" alt="Screenshot of Clip" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="IMG_5475.png" alt="Screenshot of Search" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="IMG_5485.png" alt="Screenshot of Item Details" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="flyer.png" alt="Screenshot Notifications" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="IMG_5484.png" alt="Screenshot of Sync" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="/images/flipp/coupons/features/screen-coupons.png" alt="Screenshot of Discount Slider" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Carousel nav -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

div

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I am unable to get both sliders working at the same time also I dont know if images height and width are also a problem

Comment: I have attached the image of the problem I also need to add a nexus png as well